# How to use column name from a file in hive

Tags: shell, hive, beeline

Very new to Beeline and bigdata stuff .

How can I use column names in Beeline in Shell Script. For example

```
ColNames=Emp_id,Emp_name,Emp_City
Tbl_name=Employee
DB_Name=HR_Dept

Select $ColNames from $Tbl_name.$DB_Name;
```

1.Is it possible to use in Beeline/Hive and
2. Can I place the file in the Linux box , Let's Say columnsnamesonly.txt and call the values in beeline from Script

```
Columnnamesonly.txt

empid,emp_name,emp_city

select $/tmp/colnamesonly.txt from Employee.hr_dept;
```

Sorry for the basic question . I cant find answer anywhere whether it is possible or not .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then, yes, you can pass in variables saved in a text file. **The below assumes you are already using beeline to run hive.

Add your variables to a new hiverc file

1. Open your hiverc file for editing. Using vim this might look like: `vim ~/.hiverc`
2. Edit the file by adding a line for each variable you want: `set hivevar:variable_name=column_one;`  (If you are unfamiliar with vim, I suggest reading some basic material or using something else to edit the file)
3. Save the file to whatever path you want. The vim command would look like `:w filepath/newhivercfile`

Call your variables in your hive script

4. Edit your hive script adding variables where needed, for example: `SELECT ${variable_name} FROM table;` Let's save this in `filepath/script.hql`

Run script with your variables!

5. Run your hive script using your regular beeline but adding:

   1. `-i filepath/newhivercfile` this points hive to the hiverc file you created in step 1
   2. `-f filepath/script.hql` this runs the hive script  you created in step 4.

All together your beeline query will look something like: `beeline -i filepath/newhivercfile -u jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2.com:10000 $USER org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -f filepath/script.hql`

Comment: Nice Suggestion. However is there anyway to achieve this without editing in ~.hiverc . The main thing why I want to do this is because I have 400+ columns in my table. This seems very clumsy in my script .  If I move this file to production , They will not allow me to edit in hiverc file .

Comment: I don't know of a way to make beeline read in multiple parameter files. I don't think it's clumsy to put all your parameters in a .hiverc, that is what it is for. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful for your situation.